# Method Not Allowed with FosRestBundle

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, fosrestbundle

I have an API with some controllers for their respective entities. They have all the same structure, but in one of them I have this error when I try to delete a value.

> No route found for "DELETE /api/categories/4": Method Not Allowed (Allow: GET, HEAD, PUT)

But I have the delete action created! And in other controllers, with the same code, it works fine.

The delete action:

```
/**     
 * @return array  
 * @Rest\Delete("/categories/{id}")      
 * @Rest\View(statusCode=204)
 * @Method({"DELETE"})       
 */
public function deleteCategoryAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); 
    $category = $em->getRepository('CASEventBundle:Category')->find($id);

    $em->remove($category);
    $em->flush();

    return new View("deleted successfully", Response::HTTP_OK);
}
```

The routing file:

```
category:
    type: rest
    resource: CAS\APIRestBundle\Controller\CategoryController
```

Comment: Do you have any other working Delete methods in your application?

Comment: Yes, and they have the same code and structure and there is no problem with them

Comment: What does `app/console debug:router` command show, does it see this route? Have you tried clearing cache?

Comment: Yes, I have cleared cache and it keeps doing the same. And about the command, it doesn't shows the route. Where it should be the delete_category is the index.

Comment: index                               GET        ANY      ANY    /api/index.{_format}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved it. It was a class name that it was repeated in other file.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but try by using `methods` in route

```
category:
    type: rest
    resource: CAS\APIRestBundle\Controller\CategoryController
    methods: [DELETE]
```

[Ref Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30956943/symfony2-routing-method-not-allowed-allow-method)

Comment: It doesn't works. It's very strange, because the other controllers work fine, and the others actions in CategoryController(get, post, put) also work well.